# MongoDB return all documents (even if they are double)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let say I have an array with some document _id's:

```
const ids = ["5ffd5eb822084969b4dc9f74","5ffd5eb822084969b4dc9f74"]
```

As you can see, there are duplicated, so I want both documents back from Mongo. But with the `Document.find({_id: {$in: ids}})` query and the `$all` option only one document is returned.

Is there a way to get the transaction twice (in this case) back from Mongo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop iterate over the array of ids and and use `Document.find(id)` multiple times.

```
const ids = ["5ffd5eb822084969b4dc9f74","5ffd5eb822084969b4dc9f74"];
const result = [];
// Loop through each element
ids.forEach(async(id) => {
    const foundResult = await Document.find({_id: id});
    result.push(foundResult);
})
```

Then you can use the result array.